# independent devices (Threads)

Tags: python, multithreading, pyserial

Which is the est way to manage device from code in python?
My Device object should:

- regularly and indepenedent send query to devices to check stack of errors,
- detecting connection lost,
- allows other threads to queuing queries (and returns result to other thread, which is waiting for some data)
  and i dont know how to write it..

I once read in one of the comments here that the best option when multiple threads want to use a single object for communication is to create a command queue for it. The object's task is to collect the commands one by one and send them to the device, and that sounds good.

The problem arises when the sent command is expected to return something, and the response needs to be passed to the appropriate place. After all, we want the devices to be independent. Here, the topic seems quite simple - expand the command with additional data, such as the ID of the object to which the response belongs, and so on.

The device should regularly (every x time or queries) send some request to the physical device to verify if everything is okay with it (e.g., request an error stack).

The only solution that comes to mind is to create some kind of data container object in which the device would update the data, and another thread would retrieve it. However, this solution has its drawbacks - sometimes, right after sending the data, I would like the second thread to start with fresh data.

What about the case when for each iteration, I will need data from 2 or more devices? Should I then create an infinite loop in each iteration and continue only when both containers are full?